# QUDPSocket can't receive from remote Ethernet

Tags: c++, windows, qt, sockets

Currently I am writing an application for Windows 10 to read UDP packets with a QUDPSocket through the Ethernet adapted to thunderbolt.

WireShark and Microsoft UDP Receiver/Sender both see the proper UDP packets and where each sender ip address, port#, local ip address and local port# are.

But whenever I try to use QUDPSocket, it has trouble receiving any packets. The readyRead() is never signaled.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {
    socket = new QUdpSocket(this);
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(processPendingDatagrams()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
    socket->bind(QHostAddress::AnyIPv4, 56666);
}

void MainWindow::processPendingDatagrams()
{
    QByteArray array;
    QHostAddress sender;
    quint16 senderPort;


 while (socket->hasPendingDatagrams())
    {
        array.fill(0, socket->pendingDatagramSize());

        socket->readDatagram(array.data(),
                                array.size(),
                                &sender,
                                &senderPort);
        qDebug()<<socket->pendingDatagramSize();
    }
}
```

I tried multiple versions of binding but none worked. 
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Please, edit your post to add the constructor of your `socket`.

Comment: And the implementation of `readDatagrams()` too.

Comment: Hi, here is the way they are set up @MohammedDeifallah

Comment: I don't have an accurate solution. However, try to interchange the two lines of connection and binding. Try to use the default `connect` method without specifying `Qt::Queued connection` too. Also, try to make sure of the host and port of your socket.